Using Python and awoxmeshlight or bluepy, cannot connect to an EGLO BTLE bulb, even if detected using hcitool lescan
Using a RaspberryPi 4B running Raspbian buster, I can run hcitool lescan --discovery=g and see the mac address of the EGLO bulb needed.
I have tried an example programme using awoxmeshlight (the bulb works from my tablet using the Awox app):-
import awoxmeshlight
from bluepy import btle
from pprint import pprint
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("awoxmeshlight")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler ()
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler (handler)

AWOX_EGLO_BUL_MAC = <MAC Address> # EGLO lamp MAC address

AWOX_USER = <app account username>
AWOX_PASS = <app account password>
AWOX_MESH_NAME = <app account username>
AWOX_MESH_PWD = <app account password>


mylight = awoxmeshlight.AwoxMeshLight (AWOX_EGLO_BUL_MAC, AWOX_USER, AWOX_PASS)
# res = mylight.connect() # Never managed to get this work - always crashed
# res = mylight.connect(AWOX_USER, AWOX_PASS) # Didn't work & crashed
res = mylight.connectWithRetry() # => got further before crashing - get model number
# res = mylight.connectWithRetry(1, AWOX_USER, AWOX_PASS) # => got further before crashing - get model number

# p = btle.Peripheral(AWOX_EGLO_BUL_MAC, btle.ADDR_TYPE_RANDOM) 


I have tried a range of options for the usernames and passwords including '' without any success.
If I try e.g. res=mylight.connect(), I get e.g.:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/<DIRECTORY>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awoxmeshlight/__init__.py", line 116, in connect
    self.btdevice.connect (self.mac)
  File "/<DIRECTORY>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 445, in connect
    self._connect(addr, addrType, iface)
  File "/<DIRECTORY>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 439, in _connect
    raise BTLEDisconnectError("Failed to connect to peripheral %s, addr type: %s" % (addr, addrType), rsp)
bluepy.btle.BTLEDisconnectError: Failed to connect to peripheral <MAC ADDRESS>, addr type: public


If I try res=mylight.connectWithRetry(1) I get:-
res = False, but the programme doesn't crash.
Asa  result of the error message referencing bluepy, I thought I would try to see the result of trying to connect using bluepy:
If I try p = btle.Peripheral(AWOX_EGLO_BUL_MAC, btle.ADDR_TYPE_RANDOM) , I get:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/<DIRECTORY>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 391, in __init__
    self._connect(deviceAddr, addrType, iface)
  File "/<DIRECTORY>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bluepy/btle.py", line 439, in _connect
    raise BTLEDisconnectError("Failed to connect to peripheral %s, addr type: %s" % (addr, addrType), rsp)
bluepy.btle.BTLEDisconnectError: Failed to connect to peripheral <MAC ADDRESS>, addr type: random

I have tried connecting using bluepy with both the btle.ADDR_TYPE_RANDOM and btle.ADDR_TYPE_PUBLIC with the same result.
Using the blueman Bluetooth Manager on the 'Pi, I can "trust" the device, but cannot pair with it.
I don't know much about this topic, but would really be grateful if someone knows how to connect to the EGLO bulb using Bluetooth, I hope this may allow me to get the awoxmeshlight library to work!
I also tried sudo btmgmt le on before trying to connect using btle.Peripheral... without success (I think this was a distraction, as I could "trust" the device using blueman.
My apologies if I have been too verbose or missed important information, but I am very new to all of this.
Please let me know if you would like more details.
Many thanks,
=============
Following the comment from @ukBaz (many thanks), I tried both the journalctl and sudo btmon, and neither results meant anything to me. Here is some of the output of sudo btmon:
@ RAW Open: blueman-manager version 2.22                      {0x000d} 9.857958
@ RAW Close: blueman-manager                                  {0x000d} 9.858224
@ MGMT Open: bluepy-helper version 1.18                      {0x000d} 10.617605
@ MGMT Command: Read Management Version I.. (0x0001) plen 0  {0x000d} 10.618027
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 6               {0x000d} 10.618053
      Read Management Version Information (0x0001) plen 3
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Version: 1.18
< HCI Command: LE Remove Device Fro.. (0x08|0x0012) plen 7  #1 [hci0] 10.619371
        Address type: Public (0x00)
        Address: A4:C1:38:93:D5:EB (Telink Semiconductor (Taipei) Co. Ltd.)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                 #2 [hci0] 10.620637
      LE Remove Device From White List (0x08|0x0012) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Add Device To Whi.. (0x08|0x0011) plen 7  #3 [hci0] 10.620789
        Address type: Random (0x01)
        Address: A4:C1:38:93:D5:BE (Reserved)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                 #4 [hci0] 10.621239
      LE Add Device To White List (0x08|0x0011) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) plen 7  #5 [hci0] 10.621317
        Type: Passive (0x00)
        Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in white list (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                 #6 [hci0] 10.621647
      LE Set Scan Parameters (0x08|0x000b) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) plen 2      #7 [hci0] 10.621718
        Scanning: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                 #8 [hci0] 10.622304
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
@ RAW Open: blueman-manager version 2.22                     {0x000e} 10.859384
@ RAW Close: blueman-manager                                 {0x000e} 10.859538
@ RAW Open: blueman-manager version 2.22                     {0x000e} 11.861064
@ RAW Close: blueman-manager                                 {0x000e} 11.861301
@ RAW Open: blueman-manager version 2.22                     {0x000e} 12.862724
@ RAW Close: blueman-manager                                 {0x000e} 12.862790
@ RAW Open: blueman-manager version 2.22                     {0x000e} 13.864121
@ RAW Close: blueman-manager                                 {0x000e} 13.864149
@ RAW Open: blueman-manager version 2.22                     {0x000e} 14.865127

If this does help direct my efforts, it would be appreciated.
Maybe I am going down a rabbit hole, as "all" I want to be able to do is to control an EGLO BTLE bulb, and I was trying this using the awoxmeshlight Python module, but if this is overly complex for my needs, ...!
I also tried the mesh-cfgclient, but it seemed to hang, but wanted a config file, but I couldn't find out how to generate one!
I tried to install bluez-meshd, but was unable to download - or install it using apt install.
My apologies if I am being really silly - any further guidance would be appreciated.

Bluetooth Mesh makes heavy use of AEAD-AES_CCM encryption, which is implemented in the Linux kernel. I haven't checked lately, but this was not enabled by default on Raspberry Pi so required a rebuild of the Kernel for BlueZ mesh. Rebuilding the kernel for this is documented in the study guide from the Bluetooth SIG https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Developer-Study-Guide-How-to-Deploy-BlueZ-on-a-Raspberry-Pi-Board-as-a-Bluetooth-Mesh-Provisioner.pdf. In a Linux terminal using the commands journalctl -f -u bluetooth or sudo btmon might give you more debug information

hci-tool has been deprecated. I believe the correct command line tool for working with Bluetooth Mesh on Linux is mesh-cfgclient.  You may need to install the bluez-meshd package to get this https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/bluez-meshd
